# Enumerar registros

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de enumerar los registros de cada tabla. Pero al aplicar este script me aparece que todos los registros se enumeran por 1.-

```
$(".pregunta-contenedor").each(function(){
    let iterador = 1;
    let temporal = $(this).find(".pregunta-preguntaInicial");
    temporal.each(function(){
        temporal.text(iterador + ".- " + temporal.text());
        iterador++;
    });
});
```

**Aquí hay una demostración**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".editarPregunta", function() {
          $(this)
            .parents(".pregunta-contenedor")
            .children(".pregunta-preguntaInicial")
            .attr("contentEditable", "true")
            .focus();
        });
      
        $(document).on("click", ".eliminarPregunta", function() {
          let actual = $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent();
          actual.remove();
        });
      
        $(document).on("paste", ".pregunta-preguntaInicial", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let datos = event.clipboardData.getData("text/PLAIN");
          document.execCommand("insertText", true, datos);
        });
      
        $(document).on("paste", ".panel-ficha", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let datos = event.clipboardData.getData("text/PLAIN");
          document.execCommand("insertText", true, datos);
        });

        $(document).on("paste", ".panel-aspecto-descripcion", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let datos = event.clipboardData.getData("text/PLAIN");
          document.execCommand("insertText", true, datos);
        });
        
        $(".contenedor-panel").on("click", ".panel-ficha", function() {
      var t = $(this);
      var tp = t.next();
      var p = t
        .parent()
        .siblings()
        .find(".panel-aspecto");
      tp.slideToggle();
      p.slideUp();
    });
  
    $(".contenedor-panel").on("click", ".panel-aspecto-descripcion", function() {
      var t = $(this);
      var tp = t.next();
      var p = t
        .parent()
        .siblings()
        .find(".panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores");
      tp.slideToggle();
      p.slideUp();
    });
    
    $(".comboBox").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(".radioButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(".text").removeAttr("disabled")

    $(".parrafo_editable").removeAttr("contenteditable");
    $(".pregunta-preguntaInicial").removeAttr("contenteditable");

    $(".btn-crearElemento").remove();
    $(".btn-categoria").remove();
    $(".btn-pregunta").remove();
    $(".rejilla").remove();
    $(".rejilla2").remove();
    $(".cambiar_nombre").remove();
    $(".img-panel-ficha").remove();
    $(".img-panel-aspecto-descripcion").remove();
    $(".editarPregunta").remove();
    $(".eliminarPregunta").remove();
    $(".btn-guardar").remove();

    $(".panel-aspecto").slideUp();
    $(".panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores").slideUp();
    $(".data-subnivel").parent().parent().slideUp();
    
    //------------------
    
    $(".pregunta-contenedor").each(function(){
        let iterador = 1;
        let temporal = $(this).find(".pregunta-preguntaInicial");
        temporal.each(function(){
            temporal.text(iterador + ".- " + temporal.text());
            iterador++;
        });
    });
```

```css
* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .panel-aspecto-descripcion {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 10px 15px;
        }

        .panel-ficha {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 10px 15px;
        }

        .parrafo_editable {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .btn-crearElemento {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            /* margin-top: 10px; */
        }

        .btn-categoria {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .btn-guardar {
            padding: 5px 10px;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 1.5;
            background-color: #00a65a;
            box-shadow: none;
            border: 1px solid #008d4c;
            border-radius: 3px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .comboBox:hover{
            cursor: not-allowed;
        }

        .text:hover{
            cursor: not-allowed;
        }

        .subirArchivo:hover{
            cursor: not-allowed;
        }

    /*========================================================*/

    .contenedor-panel{
        /* display: flex;
        flex-direction: column; */
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .panel-ficha{
        background: #f5f5f5;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-top-right-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        
    }

    .panel-aspecto{
        display: none;
    }

    .panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores{
        display: none;
    }

    /*------------------------------------*/

    .panel-aspecto-descripcion{
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 16px;
        background: #D7CCC8;
        border: 1px solid #A1887F;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-top-right-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #BCAAA4;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    /*---------------------------------------*/

    .panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores-descripcion{
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 16px;
        background: #FFFDE7;
        border: 1px solid #FFF9C4;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-top-right-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #BCAAA4;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    /*---------------------------------------*/

    .estilos-ficha-supervision{
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
    }

    /*=================================================================================*/

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      
      /*CONTENEDOR*/
      .contenedorTotalPreguntas {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 500;
      }
      
      /*PUNTAJE*/
      .puntaje {
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: white;
        height: 30px;
        background: #3c8dbc;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      .puntaje-hijo {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 30px;
      }
      
      .puntaje-descripcion {
        width: 41%;
      }
      
      .puntaje-puntuacion {
        width: 8%;
      }
      
      /*OBSERVACIONES*/
      .observacion {
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #333;
        height: 30px;
        background: #ecf0f5;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 5px;
      }
      
      .observacion-hijo {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 30px;
      }
      
      .observacion-descripcionInicial {
        width: 33%;
      }
      
      .observacion-puntuacion {
        width: 8%;
      }
      
      .observacion-descripcionFinal {
        width: 16%;
      }
      
      .observacion-i {
        width: 4%;
      }
      
      .observacion-malo {
        background-color: #fb86af;
      }
      
      .observacion-regular {
        background: #fbd386;
      }
      
      .observacion-bueno {
        background: #cdf69d;
      }
      
      .observacion-muyBueno {
        background: #cdf69d;
      }
      
      .observacion-acciones {
        /* width: 4%; */
        flex-grow: 1;
      }
      
      /*PREGUNTA*/
      .pregunta {
        /* font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #333;
            height: 55px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center; */
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      .pregunta-contenedor {
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #333;
        /* height: 49px; */
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      .pregunta-hijo {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 49px;
      }
      
      .pregunta-preguntaInicial {
        /* display: flex; */
        display: block;
        width: 33%;
        height: auto;
        /* justify-content: flex-start; */
        padding: 15px 15px;
        text-align: justify;
    }
      
      .pregunta-comboBox {
        width: 8%;
      }
      
      /**/
      select {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      
      option {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      /**/
      
      .pregunta-radioButton {
        width: 8%;
      }
      
      /**/
      input[type="radio"] {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      /**/
      
      .pregunta-text {
        width: 16%;
      }
      
      /*text esta dentro de .pregunta-text*/
      
      .text {
        padding: 6px 12px;
        height: 35px;
        width: 230px;
        border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
      }
      
      /*text esta dentro de .pregunta-text*/
      
      .pregunta-subirArchivo {
        width: 4%;
      }
      
      .pregunta-iconos {
        /* width: 4%; */
        flex-grow: 1;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      
      /**/
      .pregunta-iconos img {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0 5px;
      }
      /**/
      
      /*btn-pregungta esta afuera del contenedor "pregunta"*/
      
      .btn-pregunta {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="contenedor-panel"><div class="contenedor-panel-hijo"><div class="panel-ficha"><p class="parrafo_editable" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha 1</p><div class="contenedor_icon"></div></div><div class="contenedorTotalPreguntas" style="display: block;"><div class="puntaje"><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-descripcion data-subnivel">PUNTAJE</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">1</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">2</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">3</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">4</div></div><div class="observacion"><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionInicial">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion">IMPORTANCIA</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-malo">MALO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-regular">REGULAR</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-bueno">BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-muyBueno">MUY BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionFinal">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-i"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-acciones">ACCIONES</div></div><div class="pregunta"><form class="pregunta-contenedor"><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA 1.0.1</div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox"><select class="comboBox"><option value="Vacio" selected="">--Seleccione--</option><option value="Alta">Alta</option><option value="Media">Media</option><option value="Baja">Baja</option></select></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="1" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="2" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="3" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="4" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><button class="subirArchivo" type="button" value="i" disabled=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos"></div></form></div></div></div><div class="contenedor-panel-hijo"><div class="panel-ficha"><p class="parrafo_editable" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha 2</p><div class="contenedor_icon"></div></div><div class="panel-aspecto" style="display: block;"><div contenteditable="false" class="panel-aspecto-descripcion"><p class="parrafo_editable" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_aspecto_descripcion 2.1</p><div class="contenedor_icon"></div></div><div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores" style="display: none;"><div class="contenedorTotalPreguntas"><div class="puntaje"><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-descripcion">PUNTAJE</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">1</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">2</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">3</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">4</div></div><div class="observacion"><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionInicial">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion">IMPORTANCIA</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-malo">MALO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-regular">REGULAR</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-bueno">BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-muyBueno">MUY BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionFinal">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-i"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-acciones">ACCIONES</div></div><div class="pregunta"><form class="pregunta-contenedor"><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA 2.1.1</div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox"><select class="comboBox"><option value="Vacio" selected="">--Seleccione--</option><option value="Alta">Alta</option><option value="Media">Media</option><option value="Baja">Baja</option></select></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="1" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="2" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="3" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="4" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><button class="subirArchivo" type="button" value="i" disabled=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos"></div></form><form class="pregunta-contenedor"><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA 2.1.2</div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox"><select class="comboBox"><option value="Vacio" selected="">--Seleccione--</option><option value="Alta">Alta</option><option value="Media">Media</option><option value="Baja">Baja</option></select></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="1" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="2" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="3" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="4" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><button class="subirArchivo" type="button" value="i" disabled=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos"></div></form></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: iterator esta dentro del each siempre sera 1 porque le asiganas eso debes sacarlo del each o hacerlo asi `$(".pregunta-contenedor").each( function( key, value ){ let iterator=key++; //resto del codigo! }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que el contador que creas se reinicia a 1 en cada iteración. La función [.each de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/each/) recibe como parámetro una función que puede, a su vez, recibir 2 parámetros: la posición del elemento en la lista y el elemento en sí. Puedes usar este contador entu tu función:

```
$(".pregunta-contenedor").each(function(indice, elemento){
    let iterador = indice + 1;
    //elemento === this
    let temporal = $(elemento).find(".pregunta-preguntaInicial");
    temporal.each(function(){
        temporal.text(iterador + ".- " + temporal.text());
        iterador++;
    });
});
```

este código tiene otra cosa incorrecta:

```
    temporal.each(function(){
        temporal.text(iterador + ".- " + temporal.text());
        iterador++;
    });
```

Estás recorriendo la colección de elementos `temporal`, pero en cada iteración llamas a `temporal.text(...)`, lo que cambia el texto a **todos** los elementos de la colección. Deberías hacer algo como:

```
temporal.each(function(indice2, elemento2){
    $(elemento2).text((indice2 + 1) + ".- " + elemento2.text());
});
```

```js
$(document).on("click", ".editarPregunta", function() {
  $(this)
    .parents(".pregunta-contenedor")
    .children(".pregunta-preguntaInicial")
    .attr("contentEditable", "true")
    .focus();
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".eliminarPregunta", function() {
    let actual = $(this)
      .parent()
      .parent();
    actual.remove();
  });

  $(document).on("paste", ".pregunta-preguntaInicial", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let datos = event.clipboardData.getData("text/PLAIN");
    document.execCommand("insertText", true, datos);
  });

  $(document).on("paste", ".panel-ficha", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let datos = event.clipboardData.getData("text/PLAIN");
    document.execCommand("insertText", true, datos);
  });

  $(document).on("paste", ".panel-aspecto-descripcion", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let datos = event.clipboardData.getData("text/PLAIN");
    document.execCommand("insertText", true, datos);
  });

  $(".contenedor-panel").on("click", ".panel-ficha", function() {
  var t = $(this);
  var tp = t.next();
  var p = t
    .parent()
    .siblings()
    .find(".panel-aspecto");
  tp.slideToggle();
  p.slideUp();
});

$(".contenedor-panel").on("click", ".panel-aspecto-descripcion", function() {
  var t = $(this);
  var tp = t.next();
  var p = t
    .parent()
    .siblings()
    .find(".panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores");
  tp.slideToggle();
  p.slideUp();
});

$(".comboBox").removeAttr("disabled");
$(".radioButton").removeAttr("disabled");
$(".text").removeAttr("disabled")

$(".parrafo_editable").removeAttr("contenteditable");
$(".pregunta-preguntaInicial").removeAttr("contenteditable");

$(".btn-crearElemento").remove();
$(".btn-categoria").remove();
$(".btn-pregunta").remove();
$(".rejilla").remove();
$(".rejilla2").remove();
$(".cambiar_nombre").remove();
$(".img-panel-ficha").remove();
$(".img-panel-aspecto-descripcion").remove();
$(".editarPregunta").remove();
$(".eliminarPregunta").remove();
$(".btn-guardar").remove();

$(".panel-aspecto").slideUp();
$(".panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores").slideUp();
$(".data-subnivel").parent().parent().slideUp();

//------------------

$(".pregunta-contenedor").each(function(indice, elemento){
  let iterador = indice + 1;
  //elemento === this
  let temporal = $(elemento).find(".pregunta-preguntaInicial");
  temporal.each(function(indice2, elemento2){
    $(elemento2).text((indice + 1) + ".- " + $(elemento2).text());
  });
});
```

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .panel-aspecto-descripcion {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 10px 15px;
  }

  .panel-ficha {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 10px 15px;
  }

  .parrafo_editable {
      margin: 0;
  }

  .btn-crearElemento {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      /* margin-top: 10px; */
  }

  .btn-categoria {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .btn-guardar {
      padding: 5px 10px;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      background-color: #00a65a;
      box-shadow: none;
      border: 1px solid #008d4c;
      border-radius: 3px;
      color: #fff;
  }

  .comboBox:hover{
      cursor: not-allowed;
  }

  .text:hover{
      cursor: not-allowed;
  }

  .subirArchivo:hover{
      cursor: not-allowed;
  }

/*========================================================*/

.contenedor-panel{
  /* display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; */
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.panel-ficha{
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.panel-aspecto{
  display: none;
}

.panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores{
  display: none;
}

/*------------------------------------*/

.panel-aspecto-descripcion{
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #D7CCC8;
  border: 1px solid #A1887F;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #BCAAA4;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/*---------------------------------------*/

.panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores-descripcion{
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #FFFDE7;
  border: 1px solid #FFF9C4;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #BCAAA4;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/*---------------------------------------*/

.estilos-ficha-supervision{
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}

/*=================================================================================*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*CONTENEDOR*/
.contenedorTotalPreguntas {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

/*PUNTAJE*/
.puntaje {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  background: #3c8dbc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.puntaje-hijo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
}

.puntaje-descripcion {
  width: 41%;
}

.puntaje-puntuacion {
  width: 8%;
}

/*OBSERVACIONES*/
.observacion {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ecf0f5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.observacion-hijo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
}

.observacion-descripcionInicial {
  width: 33%;
}

.observacion-puntuacion {
  width: 8%;
}

.observacion-descripcionFinal {
  width: 16%;
}

.observacion-i {
  width: 4%;
}

.observacion-malo {
  background-color: #fb86af;
}

.observacion-regular {
  background: #fbd386;
}

.observacion-bueno {
  background: #cdf69d;
}

.observacion-muyBueno {
  background: #cdf69d;
}

.observacion-acciones {
  /* width: 4%; */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/*PREGUNTA*/
.pregunta {
  /* font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #333;
      height: 55px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center; */
  width: 100%;
}

.pregunta-contenedor {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  /* height: 49px; */
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.pregunta-hijo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 49px;
}

.pregunta-preguntaInicial {
  /* display: flex; */
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  /* justify-content: flex-start; */
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.pregunta-comboBox {
  width: 8%;
}

/**/
select {
  cursor: pointer;
}

option {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/**/

.pregunta-radioButton {
  width: 8%;
}

/**/
input[type="radio"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/**/

.pregunta-text {
  width: 16%;
}

/*text esta dentro de .pregunta-text*/

.text {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 230px;
  border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
}

/*text esta dentro de .pregunta-text*/

.pregunta-subirArchivo {
  width: 4%;
}

.pregunta-iconos {
  /* width: 4%; */
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

/**/
.pregunta-iconos img {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
/**/

/*btn-pregungta esta afuera del contenedor "pregunta"*/

.btn-pregunta {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="contenedor-panel"><div class="contenedor-panel-hijo"><div class="panel-ficha"><p class="parrafo_editable" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha 1</p><div class="contenedor_icon"></div></div><div class="contenedorTotalPreguntas" style="display: block;"><div class="puntaje"><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-descripcion data-subnivel">PUNTAJE</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">1</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">2</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">3</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">4</div></div><div class="observacion"><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionInicial">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion">IMPORTANCIA</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-malo">MALO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-regular">REGULAR</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-bueno">BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-muyBueno">MUY BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionFinal">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-i"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-acciones">ACCIONES</div></div><div class="pregunta"><form class="pregunta-contenedor"><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA 1.0.1</div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox"><select class="comboBox"><option value="Vacio" selected="">--Seleccione--</option><option value="Alta">Alta</option><option value="Media">Media</option><option value="Baja">Baja</option></select></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="1" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="2" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="3" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="4" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><button class="subirArchivo" type="button" value="i" disabled=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos"></div></form></div></div></div><div class="contenedor-panel-hijo"><div class="panel-ficha"><p class="parrafo_editable" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_ficha 2</p><div class="contenedor_icon"></div></div><div class="panel-aspecto" style="display: block;"><div contenteditable="false" class="panel-aspecto-descripcion"><p class="parrafo_editable" onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">panel_aspecto_descripcion 2.1</p><div class="contenedor_icon"></div></div><div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores" style="display: none;"><div class="contenedorTotalPreguntas"><div class="puntaje"><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-descripcion">PUNTAJE</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">1</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">2</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">3</div><div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">4</div></div><div class="observacion"><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionInicial">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion">IMPORTANCIA</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-malo">MALO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-regular">REGULAR</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-bueno">BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-muyBueno">MUY BUENO</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionFinal">OBSERVACIONES</div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-i"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="observacion-hijo observacion-acciones">ACCIONES</div></div><div class="pregunta"><form class="pregunta-contenedor"><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA 2.1.1</div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox"><select class="comboBox"><option value="Vacio" selected="">--Seleccione--</option><option value="Alta">Alta</option><option value="Media">Media</option><option value="Baja">Baja</option></select></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="1" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="2" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="3" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="4" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><button class="subirArchivo" type="button" value="i" disabled=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos"></div></form><form class="pregunta-contenedor"><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA 2.1.2</div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox"><select class="comboBox"><option value="Vacio" selected="">--Seleccione--</option><option value="Alta">Alta</option><option value="Media">Media</option><option value="Baja">Baja</option></select></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="1" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="2" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="3" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" value="4" type="radio" name="rButton"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text"></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><button class="subirArchivo" type="button" value="i" disabled=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div><div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos"></div></form></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```